# How to upload a file and save it in an specific folder in local computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I want to take (upload) a file to a specific folder that I have created in my project (on local computer not a server!).

Here is the code that I am using:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/" + filename));
```

I have added the Fileupload, and the code above in a button. But the code won't work. What's the problem?

I also used this form:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~DesktopModules/UshtrimiDyte/images/" + filename));
```

I also used it with double back slashes, but that didn't work either. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: how about the errors you got?

Comment: You can't save files to the visitors machine using ASP.NET. For this write WinForms application and have him use it instead of a web site.

Comment: @Vogel612, I have no errors :(.... it just doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try the above

```
 string path = Server.MapPath("~DesktopModules/UshtrimiDyte/images/" + filename);   
 System.IO.Stream myStream;
        Int32 fileLen;
        byte[] Input = null;
        fileLen = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        if (fileLen > 0)
        {
            Input = new Byte[fileLen];
            myStream = FileUpload1.FileContent;
            myStream.Read(Input, 0, fileLen);
            string I_Docx_type = FileUploadFieldDoc.FileName.Substring(FileUpload1.FileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            WriteToFile(path +  "." +I_Docx_type, ref Input);
            path += "." + I_Docx_type;

        }
```

method

```
 private void WriteToFile(string strPath, ref byte[] Buffer)
    {
        // Create a file
        System.IO.FileStream newFile = new System.IO.FileStream(strPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

        // Write data to the file
        newFile.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

        // Close file
        newFile.Close();

    }
```

Comment: The above code is to store a file from client to your server.

Comment: I am working on my computer... i really need this for my computer :(

Comment: Asp.net c# is server based. The logic to is that tou build on your pc in order to upload to a server that users can access it. So So you develop the app on your pc and you debug it as client. BUT the file which YOU the client try to save, is on YOUR pc (future server). So the client saves docs to the server. Besides what is the  meaning for a client to save file locally through web?

Comment: i am working on a NOT important project... I am learnin asp.net, and I have been told to do this task. I am searching since 2 days  but i can't find anything!!

Comment: This is no matter of importance. That is how asp.net and fileuploader work.